# What does "move down the agenda" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Does it mean "was discussed after the Gleneagles agreement"?

> Developing country debt **moved down the international agenda** following the Gleneagles agreement in which the G7 industrial countries agreed to spend £30bn writing off the debts owed to the International Monetary Fund and the World Bank by the 18 poor countries.

Source: *The Guardian:* [Developing countries at risk from US rate rise, debt charity warns](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2018/mar/18/developing-countries-risk-from-us-rate-rise-jubilee-debt-campaign-warns)

Comment: If the intended meaning is "became less urgent" then **down the agenda** strikes my ear as unidiomatic in this *intransitive* use of **move**. I would expect *moved down **on** the agenda*. Compare https://books.google.com/books?id=URDy68efjkEC&pg=PA2&dq=%22down+on+the+agenda%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjs5IK9o_jZAhVxm-AKHer2CJoQ6AEIQzAE#v=onepage&q=%22down%20on%20the%20agenda%22&f=false

Comment: The debt country topic became less important due to an agreement by the G7

Comment: When people **move down the agenda** they address each agenda item in turn.  The author seems to be conflating the two phrases.

Comment: X **moved down the agenda**=statement of fact by the journalist. It means to become less important. They moved the issue down the agenda.Generally, the passive would be used: X was moved down the agenda.